# Doubling measure and Riesz Potential

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, geometric-measure-theory

I am currently trying to solve some analysis exercises on metric spaces, but I cannot quite tackle on of them. The exercises read as follows:

Define the measure $$\mu_x:=\frac{d(\bullet,x)}{\mu(B(x,d(\bullet,x)))}\mu $$ where $B(x,R)$ denotes a ball centered at $x$ of radius $R$. We call this the *Riesz potential centered at $x$*.

> **Exercise 1**: Assume $\mu$ is doubling. Show that
>   $$\mu_x(B(x,R))\approx R$$
>   **Exercise 2**: Assume $\mu$ is doubling, $E$ Borel. Let $x$ be a Lebesgue point of $E$ wrt $\mu$; prove that $x$ is a Lebesgue point of $E$ wrt $\mu_x$.

I've been able to solve Exercise $1$ by cutting up the Ball into a sequence of annuli of decreasing radius and using the doubling property on those to bound the integral by above and below and get the stated result.

For Exercise $2$ I first thought that one could see this as a kind of Corollary to the first ( I've also tried to solve it analogously to the previous one), but all my tries have lead nowhere. Can someone give me a hint on how to start? And thus why do we want to assume the Borel property?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exercise 2 works similarly to the first using dyadic annuli centered at $x$. Let $$A_n=\{y: 2^{-n-1}\le d(x,y)<2^{-n}\}, \quad n=1,2,\dots$$
Since   $x$ is a Lebesgue point of $E$ and $\mu$ is doubling, we have 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\mu(A_n\setminus E)}{\mu(A_n)}= 0 \tag{1}
$$
(Indeed, the denominator is comparable to $\mu(B(x,2^{-n}))$ by the doubling property.)

On the set $A_n$, the factor $d(y,x)/\mu(B(x,d(y,x)))$ is approximately constant, i.e., pinched between two positive constants whose ratio depends only on the doubling constant of $\mu$. This and (1) imply 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\mu_x(A_n\setminus E)}{\mu_x(A_n)}= 0 \tag{2}
$$
Property (2) implies that $x$ is a Lebesgue point of $E$ wrt $\mu_x$.

Comment: Thank you. In my attempted solution I overcomplicated things and got stuck throughout the calculations, but this clearly shows how analogous it was to the previous one, as suspected.