# Doubling measure of an annulus

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Recall that a doubling measure is a measure with the additional requirement that:

$$\mu(B_{2R})\le C_\mu \mu(B_R)$$
for some contstant $C_\mu$.

While solving some esercises related to doubling measures I encountered a problem and then asked for help in this related question ([Doubling measure and Riesz Potential](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1364324/doubling-measure-and-riesz-potential)).

I thought I had understand the fact that:

> *The measure of the annulus $A_n:=\{2^{-(n+1)}R<x\le 2^{-n}R\}$ and of the ball of radius $2^{-n}R$ are comparable*

but my many efforts to give an explicit interpretation of this phenomenon haven't brought me anywhere: it is indeed clear that we can easily find an upper bound for the mass of the annulus via
$$\mu(A_n)=\mu(B_{2^{-n}R})-\mu(B_{2^{-(n+1)}R})\le C_\mu\cdot \mu(B_{2^{-(n+1)}R})-\mu(B_{2^{-(n+1)}R})=(C_\mu-1)\cdot \mu(B_{2^{-(n+1)}R})$$
But how to find a lower bound which is comparable to $\mu(B_{2^{-(n+1)}R})$ (and thus is not zero)? I've tried using convex sums of $\mu(B_{2^{-n}R}),\mu(B_{2^{-(n+1)}R})$ but it did not seem to work.

PS: notice that I am actually trying to find good bounds for:
$$I:=\int_{A_n}\frac{d(x,y)}{\mu(B(x,d(x,y))}dy$$
So to be able to estimate (/prove that)
$$J= \int_{B_R}\frac{d(x,y)}{\mu(B(x,d(x,y))}dy=\sum_{n\ge 0} \int_{A_n}\frac{d(x,y)}{\mu(B(x,d(x,y))}dy\approx R$$
So far I have found (using the above):
$$I\le \frac{2^{-n}R}{\mu(B(x,2^{-(n+1)}R))}\cdot \mu(A_n)\le 2^{-n}R \cdot(C_\mu-1)$$
and
$$I \ge \frac{2^{-(n+1)}R}{\mu(B(x,2^{-n}R))}\cdot \mu(A_n)$$
and this last step is where I am stuck.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Many thanks is advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your definition of "doubling measure" you don't specify the centers of the balls. If you only assume the doubling condition for balls centered at the origin then an annulus can have measure zero and the bound you want doesn't exist.

But of course typically one assumes that condition for balls with arbitrary centers. And now the point is that the reverse inequality automatically holds:

Lemma. Suppose $\mu$ is a measure on $\Bbb R^n$ such that $\mu(B(x,2r))\le c\,\mu(B(x,r))$ for every $x\in\Bbb R^n$ and $r>0$. Then $$\mu(B(0,2r))\ge\frac{1+c^3}{c^3}\mu(B(0,r)).$$

Proof: Fix $x$ with $|x|=3r/2$. Then $B(x,r/2)\subset B(0,2r)\setminus B(0,r)$ and $B(0,r)\subset B(x,4r)$. So
$$\mu(B(0,r))\le c^3\,\mu(B(x,r/2)\le c^3(\mu(B(0,2r))-\mu(B(0,r)))).$$

The lemma makes your question about that annulus clear: $$\mu(B(0,2r)\setminus B(0,r))\ge\frac1{c^3}\mu(B(0,r))$$(And also $\mu(B(0,r))$ is comparable to $\mu(B(0,2r))$, etc.)

Comment: Lovely! Many thanks indeed. I would have never come up with that.